# Can small earth magnet’s (1/8” thick x 1/4” dia.) glued to the outside of a jigsaw with a brushless motor cause damage?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I have attached 4 small earth magnets to the outside of my (brushless motor) jigsaw to keep extra blades handy. Could they damage/interfere with the motor in anyway?

Comment: Highly unlikely. What's the distance from the magnet to the motor?

Comment: Only if they fall off and end up inside.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This question deals with the use of electric devices. This in general is considered off-topic here. That's because you can ask (and probably answer) a million questions on consumer devices without shedding any light on a real engineering problem. Furthermore in many cases like your's it is virtually impossible to answer as we lack information about the field strength of the magnets, the shielding of the motor, the BLDC-controller and so on.